# Orbit camera lookAt change

Tags: javascript, camera, three.js

Is there any possibility to change the `lookAt` target of Orbit camera?

I have it set for my 'static' camera, but when activating the orbit camera it always looks at (0,0,0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `OrbitControls` and `TrackballControls` have a property `target` which is both the center of rotation and the camera look-at position.

You can set it like so:

```
controls.target.set( x, y, z );
```

three.js r.71

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options to set the position of the camera controls target.
Use which one suits you better.

```
// One axis at a time
controls.target.x = xPos;
controls.target.y = yPos;
controls.target.z = zPos;

// All axis at once
controls.target.set( x, y, z );

// Copy another mesh's position
controls.target.copy( someMesh.position );
```